# How to kill an instance of a class after creation to free-up memory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tensorflow, memory-management

I have a python code that consists of initializing 2 classes sequentially. I initialize the class A (alignment), do something and then initialize the class B, but the class A is still on memory so there is not enough space to init class B. The classes are written in python and tensorflow. Both classes are running on GPU (single GPU).
Now, how can I kill the class A before running class B?

Also, I tried python destructor, weakRef and gc.collect().

```
import os 
import sys
from subprocess import call
import weakref 
import gc
import time

sys.path.insert(0, 'alignment')
import alignment 


## initializing class A
align = alignment.Verification('./alignment/')
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    ## do something here

## end of the class A 
print('End of pre-processing ...')
## Here, the class A should be killed!
del align
gc.collect()

## start training (using tensorflow)
command = 'CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" python3 train.py'
call([command], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days, I found that there is no way to free-up memory without killing the python interpreter in tensorflow. But, a tricky way! You can use a sub-process and append your class to it, then kill the subprocess to close tensorflow session. For example:

‍‍`first = subprocess.Popen(["python", "class_A.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
first.communicate() # wait until session end
first.kill()`

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the destructor by releasing all the resources your `alignment` class holds.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
But, how to do so? Would you please give more details regarding the content of the destructor?

Comment: Check all the attributes your `alignment` class holds. Check in your constructor and in the methods that could update your model. Then manually delete those objects in your overriden destructor